# Previous work in 2007

Tags: wo2015172178a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2015172178A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015172178A1)

I would like to introduce one article published in 2007 with the same claims:

Surfboard Instrumentation

https://ojs.ub.uni-konstanz.de/cpa/article/view/557/496

Márcio Borgonovo dos Santos

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere in this so-called question.  You state that you want to do something.  Are we to answer: “bravo!”?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. It's a PCT filing, and the inventor has never filed any actual patent application in any country, except for provisional application in Australia. The inventor filed 4 provisional application in Australia in 2004, and all four of them are LAPSED.

Comment: I believe that the PCT application has not entered national phase yet (which should be near the end of 2016), so there is still the possibility of national applications being filed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if it hasn't entered national phase, is there any entity that allows for adding prior art citation?

Comment: There is! WIPO provides a facility for [third party observations](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/faqs/third_party_observations.html). The [Patentscope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2015172178) page for this application contains a "Submit observation" button which can be used for this purpose. The submitted document will eventually be passed to the ISA/IPEA for consideration.

Comment: @Maca  Either you or daniel should add the link to an actual answer rather than just leave it in a comment.